# Apache 2.4 - how to use multiple files in files directive?

Tags: apache-2.4

I can't find any info about it in the [official documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#files).

I try to allow access to two php files, `A.php` and `B.php`.

```
<Files "A.php">
    Require all granted
</Files>

<Files "B.php">
    Require all granted
</Files>
```

Does it work like this or is there a better solution?

Comment: seems odd to me that it's not simpler to apply the same bunch of directives to a group of files. Regular expressions are a convoluted solution when file names don't have much in common.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it works like this. But you could also use a `FilesMatch` with a regular expression like:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/foobar>
    # deny access
    Require all denied

    # but allow for A.php, B.php
    <FilesMatch ^(A|B)\.php$>
        Require all granted
    </FilesMatch>

    # or alternative
    #<FilesMatch ^[AB]\.php$>
    #    Require all granted
    #</FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```